# SASS undefined variable when using @use

Tags: sass, dart-sass

I'm using some copied SASS code to start a project. It was written with @import for Ruby SASS, and I've changed it to @use for Dart SASS.

**style.scss**

```
// base
@use 'css/var' as *;
@use 'css/base' as *;
@use 'css/typography' as *;

// layouts
@use 'css/container' as *;
@use 'css/grid' as *;
```

**css/_var.scss**

```
$baseFontSize:16 !default;
$baseLineHeight:1.5 !default; 
$leading:$baseLineHeight * 1rem !default;
```

from within the directory that style.scss is in, I ran `sass --watch .`

I keep getting the error:

> Error: Undefined variable.    ╷ 10 │     font-size: ($baseFontSize /
> 16) * 100%;    │                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ╵
> css/_typography.scss 10:17  @use
> style.scss 6:1              root stylesheet

I'm using SASS version 1.43.4

Comment: Also tried adding !global to every variable definition, such as `$baseFontSize:16 !default !global;` , but that gave the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `_typography.scss` partial uses Sass variables from `css/_var.scss` then you need to add a `@use "path-to-css/_var.scss" as *;` at-rule to the `_tyopgraphy.scss` partial to load the variables. I reckon it wouldn't give an error anymore as it will know about that variable reference.

When you load `css/_var.scss` to the base stylesheet to be compiled, you can use those variables in the `style.scss` file, but the partials being loaded into the main file will have to utilize `@use` at-rules if they use variables/mixins/etc which haven't been loaded already.

> Note: You can also look into using [index files](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#index-files) with `@use` at-rules which allows you to load a directory of partials using a single `@use` call